# Which directory should I locate the PHP project in to make it work with XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my Macbook, and now I try to upload a PHP project to build an Android application that communicates with and uses MySQL.

As a newbie, I even do not have a clue where to locate the PHP project so that the XAMPP recognises it and make it work.

Comment: If you follow the documentation you will find that you need launch your web files from the '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs' folder.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okay I just found out the folder, and there are actually two - one under /xamppfiles/apache2/ and the other directly under the xamppfiles folder. Which one is the right destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **xampp** folder you will see the folder named **htdocs**.YOu can place your project in that htdocs folder.

You can run that project by using

> localhost/yourproject_folder_name

in your browser.

Hope this will help.